# How come the filename of my uploaded image is not inserting into my database?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've had a few questions about this issue already but I keep end up not really making much progress. I'm trying to upload an image onto a page and have the filename appear in the database beside the users name but it keeps appearing a zero. Why would this be? The image field is a varchar so it will save the filename. But since I then want my getProfileImage function to display the image back to the screen, should it be a blob?

Here is my controller:

```
 function __construct()
  {
   // Call the parent construct
   parent::__construct();

   $this->load->model("profiles");
   $this->load->model("profileimages");
   $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));      

 } 



   function upload()
      {
    $config = array(

        'allowed_types' =>'gif|jpg|jpeg|png',
        'upload_path' =>'./web-project-jb/assets/puploads/',
         'max_size' => 10000,
         'max_width' => 1024,
        'max_height' => 768

);


$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$img = $this->session->userdata('img');
$username = $this->session->userdata('username');
//fail show upload form
if (! $this->upload->do_upload())
{

    $error = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());

    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');


    $viewData['username'] = $username;
    $viewData['profileText'] = $this->profiles->getProfileText($username);

    $this->load->view('shared/header');
    $this->load->view('homeprofile/homeprofiletitle', $viewData);
    $this->load->view('shared/nav');
    $this->load->view('homeprofile/homeprofileview', $error, $viewData, array('error' => ' ' ));
    $this->load->view('shared/footer');

    //redirect('homeprofile/index');

}

else
{
    //successful upload so save to database, which it doesn't


    $file_data = $this->upload->data();


    $data['img'] = '/web-project-jb/assets/puploads/'.$file_data['file_name'];
    // you may want to delete the image from the server after saving it to db
    // check to make sure $data['full_path'] is a valid path
    // get upload_sucess.php from link above
    //$image = chunk_split( base64_encode( file_get_contents( $data['file_name'] ) ) );




    $this->username = $this->session->userdata('username');

    $this->profileimages->putProfileImage($username, $img);


    $data['profileimages'] = $this->profileimages->getProfileImage($username, $img);


    $viewData['username'] = $username;
    $viewData['profileText'] = $this->profiles->getProfileText($username);

    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');

    $this->load->view('shared/header');
    $this->load->view('homeprofile/homeprofiletitle', $viewData);
    $this->load->view('shared/nav');
    $this->load->view('homeprofile/homeprofileview', $data, $viewData);
    $this->load->view('shared/footer');


    //redirect('homeprofile/index');
}

  }



    function index()
     {

$username = $this->session->userdata('username');

$img = $this->session->userdata('img');

$data['profileimages'] = $this->profileimages->getProfileImage($username, $img);

$viewData['username'] = $username;
$viewData['profileText'] = $this->profiles->getProfileText($username);

$this->load->view('shared/header');
$this->load->view('homeprofile/homeprofiletitle', $viewData);
$this->load->view('shared/nav');
//$this->load->view('homeprofile/upload_form', $data);
$this->load->view('homeprofile/homeprofileview', $data, $viewData, array('error' => ' ' ) );
$this->load->view('shared/footer');
 }

}
```

My model:

```
var $proimage_path;


function ProfileImages()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->proimage_path = 'web-project-jb/assets/puploads';

}




function exists($username)
{
    $this->db->select('*')->from("profileimages")->where('user', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {

        return true;
        /*
         echo "user $user exists!";
        $row = $query->row();
        echo " and his profileimage is $row->profileimage";
        */
    }

    else

    {

        return false;
        //echo "no such user as $user!";
    }

}


function putProfileImage($username, $img)
{


    $record = array('user' => $username, 'profileimage' => $img);
    if ($this->exists($username))
    {
        $this->db->where('user', $username)->update('profileimages', $record);


    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->where('user', $username)->insert('profileimages', $record);

    }

}

function getProfileImage($img)
{

$this->db->select('*')->from('profileimages')->where('profileimage', $img);

$query = $this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
    $row = $query->row();
    return $row->profileimage;
  }

  return $img;


 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please tell me why you reading the file name from session instead of using the uploaded image file name? assuming the user has no image and you set the session when user logs in, would not that be NUll??

Comment: Which line are u referring to? The getProfileImage function? I have tried return null at the end of that already...what do I need to change in my code for this to work?

Comment: $this->profileimages->putProfileImage($username, $img); - the second parameter you passing. $img is the value from session right? should not that be the filename? try dumping the ($img or $this->session->userdata('img') and see what value you getting, if you get null,try dumping ($file_data['file_name']) and see what you get

Comment: just change the image variable to have this value $img = $file_data['file_name'];

Comment: Great that worked thanks - the img name is now appearing in the database - next I want to find out why image wont stay on the screen when i upload?

Answer (score 0):

in your controller

```
function upload() {
    if ($this->input->post('submit')) {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/album/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|jpg|png|gif|';
        $config['max_size'] = '500000';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $file = $this->upload->data();
            $keterangan = $this->input->post('keterangan');
            $this->MGallery->addGallery($file['file_name'], $keterangan);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Foto <b>' . $file['file_name'] . '</b> berhasil di upload!');
            redirect('admin/album/index', 'refresh');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Foto <b>' . $file['file_name'] . '</b> gagal di upload!');
            redirect('admin/album/lihat', 'refresh');
        }
    } else {
        redirect('admin/album/lihat', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

in your model

```
function addGallery($file_name, $keterangan) {
    $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $data = array(
        'foto' => $file_name,
        'keterangan' => $keterangan,
        'IDKategori' => $this->input->post('kategori'),
        'tgl' => $now
    );
    $this->db->insert('album', $data);
}
```

and then, in your view like this

```
<?php
if ($this->session->flashdata('message')) {
    echo "<div class='message'>" . $this->session->flashdata('message') . "</div>";
} ?>
<form action="<?= base_url(); ?>admin/album/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
    <p>
        <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <select name="kategori">
        <?php
        foreach ($gallery_cat as $key => $list) {
        ?>
            <option value="<?= $list['IDKategori'] ?>">
            <?= $list['kategori'] ?>
        </option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</p>
<p>
    <textarea name="keterangan" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
    <label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Uplaod Foto" />
    </label>
    <input type="button" value="Kembali" onClick="javascript: history.go(-1)" />
</p>
```